# Positioning headers with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, positioning

on line .52 i want the `<h2>Locations</h2>` on top of the MIDDLE `.address` div like this:

[image]

But atm the `<h2>` is just sitting on the left like this:
[image]
 and i dont know how to get it up above the middle div.

here is my git repository: https://github.com/itsolidude/Tea_Cozy

plain code:

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 69px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
}

img {
 height: 50px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

nav span {
  color: seashell;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.mission-banner {
  background-color: black;
}

.mission-banner h4 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration-color: seashell;
}

#mission {
  background-image: url(../images/img-mission-background.jpg);
  position: relative;
  margin: 70px auto 0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#tea-of-month {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto 70px;
}

#tea-of-month img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}
#locations {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(../images/img-locations-background.jpg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.address {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tea Cozy | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="./resources/images/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="our logo">
      <nav>
        <a href="#mission"><span>Mission</span></a>
        <a href="#tea-of-month"><span>Featured Tea</span></a>
        <a href="#locations"><span>Locations</span></a>
      </nav>
        </header>
  <!-- main-content,our mission -->
        <div id="mission">
          <div class="mission-banner">
            <h2>Our Mission</h2>
            <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
<!-- tea of the month -->
      <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>  <!--ERROR HERE, ITS HIDING BEHIND THE .MISSION DIV -->
      <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy?</h4>
      <div id="tea-of-month">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="A picture of Fall Berry Blitz Tea">
          <span>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="A picture of Spiced Rum Tea">
          <span>Spiced Rum Tea</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-donut.jpg" alt="A picture of Seasonal Donuts">
          <span>Seasonal Donuts</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-myrtle-ave.jpg" alt="A picture of Myrtle Ave Tea">
          <span>Myrtle Ave Tea</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg" alt="A picture of Bedford Bizarre Tea">
          <span>Bedford Bizarre Tea</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- locations section -->
      <div id="locations">
        <h2>Locations</h2>
        <div class="address">
          <h3>Downtown</h3>
          <p>384 West 4th St</p>
          <p>Suite 108</p>
          <p>Portland, Maine</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
          <h3>East Bayside</h3>
          <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
          <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
          <p>Portland, Maine</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
          <h3>Oakdale</h3>
          <p>515 Crescent Avenue</p>
          <p>Second Floor</p>
          <p>Portland, Maine</p>
        </div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

can you pls explain what and why you did it.

Comment: too broad Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Also: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob updated it

Comment: Your example is not **Minimal**. Please limit both markup and CSS to the issue you are asking about. Since you are asking about `#locations`, remove everything else. People will likely help you if the question is clear and easy to understand, because it will likely help other future visitors. If it only helps you, chances are nobody will bother. Why should I help you if you don't want to help others?

Answer (score 0):

1) Your 'header' tag is a flex and has two items 'img' and 'nav'. You have set the justify-content to space-between for this. Thats why 'img' is not at the center.

This can be solved in no. of ways. 
one quick way is shown below, which will center it in the div.

```
<header>
  <div style="margin:auto;">
    <img src="./resources/images/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="our logo">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#mission"><span>Mission</span></a>
    <a href="#tea-of-month"><span>Featured Tea</span></a>
    <a href="#locations"><span>Locations</span></a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one of the flexbox children to occupy an entire row, you need to give it `flex-shrink:0; flex-basis: 100%` and give the parent: `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```css
#locations h2 {
  flex: 1 0 100%; /* shorthand for: flex-grow:1;
                                    flex-shrink: 0;
                                    flex-basis: 100%; */
  text-align: center;
}

#locations {
  min-height: 500px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;

  flex-wrap: wrap; /* this makes it wrap */
  background-color: #f5f5f5; /* just for SO */      
}
```

```html
<div id="locations">
  <h2>Locations</h2>
  <div class="address">
    <h3>Downtown</h3>
    <p>384 West 4th St</p>
    <p>Suite 108</p>
    <p>Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
  <div class="address">
    <h3>East Bayside</h3>
    <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
    <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
    <p>Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
  <div class="address">
    <h3>Oakdale</h3>
    <p>515 Crescent Avenue</p>
    <p>Second Floor</p>
    <p>Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Centering the contents of `<h2>` is done with `text-align: center;`

Notice I also changed `height` in `min-height` (you'll need it on mobile) and `width` in `max-width` (you only want to limit it up, not down).

Comment: ty so much that helped a lot. is there also a way for me to move to h2 so its 10px away from the div?

Comment: @itsolidude You can use either [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) or [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) on the `h2`. Margin can be negative, while padding cannot. If your styles do not seem to apply, inspect the element and see what applies (and make your selector slightly stronger). A good trick is to use the same selector as the other rule and load your stylesheet last. This way you don't increase specificity of your CSS, which is quite helpful in the long run.

Comment: you are really helpful , thank you! .. if i want to reduce the horizontal-spacing between those 3 divs (lets say a space of 40 px) i would give every div its own id and set the left and right padding (to 20px each) , which seems rather unpractical. is there an easier way?

Comment: also, when i used flex-shrink:0; flex-basis: 100% and gave the parent: flex-wrap: wrap the <h2> pushes down the divs and doesnt keep them centered? is there a way so the divs dont get affected ?

Comment: They are only centered if `justify-contents` is set to `center`, `space-between` or `space-around` on parent and if their `width`s are equal. That's default flexbox behavior. Please note you are not supposed to ask subsequent questions in the same question. Answering them in comments will only help you, while the SO principle is that answering a question should also help future visitors. Please ask your questions separately and make sure you [research before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) asking.

Comment: Also check your children and parents for any unequal margin/padding values. And set them to `0`.